# Enthalpy and entropy at phase transition

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, condensation

The second law of thermodynamics states, that entropy (of the universe) always increases. Entropy can, however, be (locally) reduced when energy is provided.

At the phase transition from a relatively unordered to a more ordered state (e.g. condensation of vapor to a liquid), the entropy is lowered. At the same time, energy is released from the system (thanks to the [enthalpy of condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization#Enthalpy_of_condensation)). Naively, I would expect that I need to provide energy (instead of gaining some) to the system to lower the entropy. Why does this not contradict the second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: I don't see a contradiction.  For the system under consideration, $\Delta S=\frac{\Delta H}{T}$.  In condensation, the changes in S and H are both negative.

Comment: To piggyback, if the change in enthalpy is negative, you can relate this to the heat released to the surroundings at constant pressure. This heat energy is typically far greater in magnitude than the entropy change of the system, and we can intuitively see how this energy gives the surroundings a greater positive change in entropy through the Clausius inequality $dS \geq \frac{\delta q}{T}$

Comment: @MattHanson. Entropy and enthalpy have different units, so comparing their magnitudes is meaningless.  Furthermore, evaporation and condensation are usually closely approximated as reversible processes.

Comment: $T\Delta S$ and $H$ have the same units. I was being lazy and skipping that step for the comparison.